# identify level shifts in a time series

Tags: outliers

I have a time series as follows:

[image]

I want to identify the locations of level shifts in this time series. Are there R packages available to do the job?

Comment: You summoned the autobox add demon, which will appear in 3,2,1...

Comment: @user603 hahahahahhaah he never showed up!

Answer (score 6):

The kind of analysis for finding such shifts is called [changepoint](/questions/tagged/changepoint) analysis (see other questions tagged like this). This can be achieved my using maximum likelihood estimation, where for $m$ changepoints the likelihood function is

$$ 
L(m, \tau_{1:m}, \theta_{1:(m+1)}) = \prod_{i=1}^{m+1} p(y_{(\tau_{i-1} + 1):\tau_i}\mid \theta_i)
$$

where $y_1,\dots,y_n$ is your data, $1 < \tau_1 <\dots<\tau_m<n$ are the boundary points marking the changes, and probability distributions $p$ are parametrized by $\theta_i$ for each $i$-th segment.

In your case, you will be dealing with changes in the mean, but in the last segment there is a visible change in mean and variance.

As about software, there is the [changepoint](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=changepoint) package for R. If you need to forecast given the series as well, there is the [Prophet](https://research.fb.com/prophet-forecasting-at-scale/) package for both R and Python, that automatically detects the changepoints and uses them as a part of the time-series model.

> Rebecca Killick and Idris A. Eckley. (2013) [changepoint: An R Package
>   for Changepoint Analysis.](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v058i03) (online paper)
>
> Eckley, I.A., Fearnhead, P. and Killick, R. (2011) [Analysis of
>   changepoint models.](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v058i03) [in:] *Bayesian Time Series Models*, eds. D.
>   Barber, A.T. Cemgil and S. Chiappa, Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 2):

In R there are a wide range of methods/packages available for this task. A selection of them are summarized in CRAN's Task View on time series: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html. Here is the section on change detection:

> Change point detection is provided in strucchange and strucchangeRcpp
> (using linear regression models) and in trend (using nonparametric
> tests). The changepoint package provides many popular changepoint
> methods, and ecp does nonparametric changepoint detection for
> univariate and multivariate series. changepoint.np implements the
> nonparametric PELT algorithm, changepoint.mv detects changepoints in
> multivariate time series, while changepoint.geo implements the
> high-dimensional changepoint detection method GeomCP. Factor-augmented
> VAR (FAVAR) models are estimated by a Bayesian method with FAVAR.
> InspectChangepoint uses sparse projection to estimate changepoints in
> high-dimensional time series. Rbeast provides Bayesian change-point
> detection and time series decomposition. breakfast includes methods
> for fast multiple change-point detection and estimation.